# Fullcalendar Qtip on mouseover instead of eventRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, qtip2

I have an issue with attaching Qtip to the eventMousever event instead of eventRender event in fullcalendar.

The reason I want to do this is because the server that has the data is in another country and latency makes it too long to prefetch all the qtip text before calendar loads (up-to 8 seconds). I wrote ajax function that returns the needed qtip information, but the problem is that eventRender function runs before the qtip information is there. So the most logical solution, in my opinion, would be to attach qtip in the eventMouseover event (send request for qtip text via ajax and then attach qtip to the element), but I can't find how to get access to the event element from within the eventMouseover event. (I have tried attaching the qtip to $(this) of mouseover event, but nothing happens (no errors as well).

I have also tried another approach. After the calendar has been loaded I fetch all the tooltips in the background and then I try to .fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' ) but that doesn't work as expected -> For example new tooltips will not appear unless you change view/change month and only then the new tooltips (fetched in the background) will appear so I believe that rerenderEvents does not work.

Any suggestion on how I can solve this issue?

Code for the eventRender (which works):

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {

  if (event.qtip_id) {
    element.qtip({    
      content: {    
        title: $('#' + event.qtip_title_id).html(),
        text: $('#' + event.qtip_id).html()
      },
      position: { 
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        //target:  'mouse',
        adjust: { mouse: false },
        viewport: $(window),
      },
      style: {
        classes: 'bigger_font qtip-light qtip-shadow'
      },
      show:  {
        delay: 500
      },
      hide:  {
        fixed: true
      }
    });
  }
```

The code that fetches all tooltips in background after the calendar has been rendered:

```
for (i = 0; i<all_events.length; i++) {
  if (all_events[i].qtip_id) {
    //alert(all_events[i].title); 
    myevent = {
      title: all_events[i].title,
      url: all_events[i].url,
      color: all_events[i].color,
      form_id: all_events[i].form_id,
      priority: all_events[i].priority,
      qtip_id: all_events[i].qtip_id,
      qtip_title_id: all_events[i].qtip_title_id,
      qtip_dealer: all_events[i].qtip_dealer,
      qtip_country_id: all_events[i].qtip_country_id,
      qtip_customer_id: all_events[i].qtip_customer_id,
      qtip_customer_name: all_events[i].qtip_customer_name,
      qtip_id: all_events[i].qtip_id,
      qtip_id_id: all_events[i].qtip_id_id
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/calendar_generate_qtip.php',
      data: myevent,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {      
        $('#qtip_holder').html($('#qtip_holder').html() + data);
      }
    }).fail(function() {

    });
  }
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

So my question is: is it at all possible to create and display qtip in the eventMouseover event in full calendar? (as eventMouseover doesn't have access to the element of the event, at least I can't see it).

Thank you for reading.

P.S. I apologize for my broken english.

Comment: [updateEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) may work - in your loop for all_events, call $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', all_events[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the event's element on eventMouseover, it is possible.

From the FullCalendar docs, it clearly says that, within the eventMouseover's callback function, "this" is set to the event's `<div>` element and $(this) provides the same element object that you get on eventRender's callback. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventMouseover/

You have mentioned

> (I have tried attaching the qtip to $(this) of mouseover event, but nothing happens

But I believe it is normal mouseover event and not the callback.

Comment: Yeah I tried slightly different approach and $(this) did work, although I had to add ` show: 
                    {
                        event: 'mouseover',
                        delay: 500,
                        ready: true
                    },` to my qtip code in the eventMouseover event